# Tungsten exchange in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I was executing a Java code in Spark cluster with 4 executers and 4 cores each with each executor memory being 10gb. I applied repartitioning and hash partitioning at 6-7 Places and the Directed Acyclic Graph changed to this.[This is the DAG after applying partitioning,The tungsten exchanges were not appearing earlier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4hdN.png)

I wanted to know what is this tungsten exchange thing in Spark? I have never seen this earlier and neither i have mentioned about it in my code. So how it got introduced by just applying partitioning logic to my code?

Comment: Read here - https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/28/project-tungsten-bringing-spark-closer-to-bare-metal.html